For single monitor use with a computer, is there an inherent advantage of bigger monitors over smaller monitors?
Let's say someone's desk has a setup of a 32" monitor at a distance of d inches from the eyes. With an otherwise identical 24" monitor, this person can achieve the same view by placing it at d/32*24=3/4 d inches from the eyes. If this is always true, assuming d is a reasonable number, is there a reason that one prefers the 32" monitor over the 24" monitor?

so first, this question appears to be highly prone to opinion-based responses and will likely be closed unless you can refine it to ask about meaningful and quantifiable metrics. second, you don't mention the resolution of the monitors or system DPI settings, and whether they are assumed to be the same.

Most "flat" (LCD, OLED, ...) monitors have a preferred resolution, so you can evaluate a monitor on a number of factors:

Preferred resolution.
Physical size
Max FPS
Latency (related to but not identical to FPS).
Number/Type of connections.
USB Hub
Sound (built in speakers)
...

If the resolutions of two monitors were identical, then your math holds - being closer would give you the same angular resolution as a larger monitor at a further distance.
However generally larger monitors also have higher resolutions (this isn't guaranteed, so you should check the technical specs). A higher resolution monitor can display more readable text than a lower resolution monitor - assuming you are viewing it at an appropriate distance.
Another factor is people have different quality of eye-sight (and generally as you get older your vision is worse than when you were younger). Having a larger monitor with a higher resolution can also help people with worse than 20/20 vision as they can increase the font size and still display a significant amount of text. Doing this can also help reduce eye strain even if your vision is good.
